# Почему textarea в android меняет свой размер?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, вёрстка

Только начинаю печатать в поле, как сразу поле увеличивается в размере по вертикали.
И это происходит только на `андроиде` (на `iphone` не проверял).

Когда удалить на печатаный символ, то все становиться в исходное положение.

Как запретить `textarea` изменять размер своего поля?

Answer (score 2):

Задать фиксированую высоту и ширину для `textarea` с помощью `css`.

Comment: Я уже так и сделал. И не только для textarea, но и для его родителя.
Но хотел бы узнать почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит потому, что каждый браузер имеет по умолчанию некий набор базовых стилей которые он применяет к странице по умолчанию. Если создать `html` без `css`, браузер все равно отобразит теги по-своему. Ведь в браузере уже есть свои стили для элементов, которые по умолчанию применяются. В разных браузерах эти правила немного отличаются. Отличия минимальны, и на первый взгляд могут быть незаметны, но все же есть.

Именно поэтому используют `normalize.css` или `reset.css`. И если вы хотите прописать свой стиль для определенного элемента, то прописываете. Textarea не исключение.